# Failed to auto configure default logger context | JoranException: Parser configuration error occurred

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, logback

Hi I am getting below error while trying to convert xml to pdf. I am using implicit logger provided by spring boot application.

- I have tried including maven dependency for slf4j-api,slf4j-simple also tried including log4j explicitly but didn't work.
  Any help would be appreciated.

```
Failed to auto configure default logger context
Reported exception:
ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.JoranException: Parser configuration error occurred
at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.event.SaxEventRecorder.buildSaxParser(SaxEventRecorder.java:89)
at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.event.SaxEventRecorder.recordEvents(SaxEventRecorder.java:57)
at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:151)
at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:110)
at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:53)
at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.configureByResource(ContextInitializer.java:65)
at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.autoConfig(ContextInitializer.java:140)
at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.init(StaticLoggerBinder.java:84)
at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:55)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:150)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:124)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:417)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:362)
at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Slf4jAdapter.createLocationAwareLog(LogAdapter.java:130)
at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter.createLog(LogAdapter.java:91)
at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:67)
at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:59)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<clinit>(SpringApplication.java:173)
at com.abc.xyz.CrossSellServicesApplication.main(CrossSellServicesApplication.java:25)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException: unrecognized feature http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities
at org.gjt.xpp.sax2.Driver.setFeature(Driver.java:178)
at org.gjt.xpp.jaxp11.SAXParserImpl.setFeatures(SAXParserImpl.java:149)
at org.gjt.xpp.jaxp11.SAXParserImpl.<init>(SAXParserImpl.java:132)
at org.gjt.xpp.jaxp11.SAXParserFactoryImpl.newSAXParserImpl(SAXParserFactoryImpl.java:114)
at org.gjt.xpp.jaxp11.SAXParserFactoryImpl.setFeature(SAXParserFactoryImpl.java:142)
at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.event.SaxEventRecorder.buildSaxParser(SaxEventRecorder.java:82)
... 18 more
14:33:18,422 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
14:33:18,423 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
14:33:18,423 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [file:/D:/workspace/abc-crosssell/target/classes/logback.xml]
14:33:18,452 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.event.SaxEventRecorder@1fcd12c - Parser configuration error occurred org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException: unrecognized feature http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities
at org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException: unrecognized feature http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities
at  at org.gjt.xpp.sax2.Driver.setFeature(Driver.java:178)
at  at org.gjt.xpp.jaxp11.SAXParserImpl.setFeatures(SAXParserImpl.java:149)
at  at org.gjt.xpp.jaxp11.SAXParserImpl.<init>(SAXParserImpl.java:132)
at  at org.gjt.xpp.jaxp11.SAXParserFactoryImpl.newSAXParserImpl(SAXParserFactoryImpl.java:114)
at  at org.gjt.xpp.jaxp11.SAXParserFactoryImpl.setFeature(SAXParserFactoryImpl.java:142)
at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.event.SaxEventRecorder.buildSaxParser(SaxEventRecorder.java:82)
at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.event.SaxEventRecorder.recordEvents(SaxEventRecorder.java:57)
at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:151)
at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:110)
at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:53)
at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.configureByResource(ContextInitializer.java:65)
at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.autoConfig(ContextInitializer.java:140)
at  at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.init(StaticLoggerBinder.java:84)
at  at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:55)
at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:150)
at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:124)
at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:417)
at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:362)
at  at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Slf4jAdapter.createLocationAwareLog(LogAdapter.java:130)
at  at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter.createLog(LogAdapter.java:91)
at  at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:67)
at  at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:59)
at  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<clinit>(SpringApplication.java:173)
at  at com.abc.xyz.CrossSellServicesApplication.main(CrossSellServicesApplication.java:25)

Logging system failed to initialize using configuration from 'null'
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not initialize Logback logging from classpath:logback.xml
at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:168)
at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.reinitialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:232)
at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initializeWithConventions(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:73)
at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initialize(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:60)
at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.initialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:132)
at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:313)
at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initialize(LoggingApplicationListener.java:282)
at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:240)
at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:216)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131)
at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:85)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:66)
at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:120)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:114)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:65)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:338)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:296)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1290)
at com.abc.xyz.CrossSellServicesApplication.main(CrossSellServicesApplication.java:25)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.JoranException: Parser configuration error occurred
at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.event.SaxEventRecorder.buildSaxParser(SaxEventRecorder.java:89)
at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.event.SaxEventRecorder.recordEvents(SaxEventRecorder.java:57)
at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:151)
at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:110)
at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:53)
at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.configureByResourceUrl(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:188)
at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:165)
... 28 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException: unrecognized feature http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities
at org.gjt.xpp.sax2.Driver.setFeature(Driver.java:178)
at org.gjt.xpp.jaxp11.SAXParserImpl.setFeatures(SAXParserImpl.java:149)
at org.gjt.xpp.jaxp11.SAXParserImpl.<init>(SAXParserImpl.java:132)
at org.gjt.xpp.jaxp11.SAXParserFactoryImpl.newSAXParserImpl(SAXParserFactoryImpl.java:114)
at org.gjt.xpp.jaxp11.SAXParserFactoryImpl.setFeature(SAXParserFactoryImpl.java:142)
at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.event.SaxEventRecorder.buildSaxParser(SaxEventRecorder.java:82)
... 34 more

Process finished with exit code 0
```

My logback.xml file.

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<property name="LOG_ROOT" value="./logs"/>
<property name="LOG_FILE_NAME" value="abc-xyz"/>
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>[%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sss'Z'}] [%C] [%t] [%L] [%-5p] %m%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="FILE-ROLLING" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${LOG_ROOT}/${LOG_FILE_NAME}.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${LOG_ROOT}/${LOG_FILE_NAME}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.gz</fileNamePattern>
        <!-- each archived file's size will be max 10MB -->
        <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
        <!-- 30 days to keep -->
        <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
        <!-- total size of all archive files, if total size > 100GB, it will delete old archived file -->
        <totalSizeCap>100GB</totalSizeCap>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>[%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sss'Z'}] [%C] [%t] [%L] [%-5p] %m%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-ROLLING"/>
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
</root>
```

My pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.2</version>
    <relativePath /> 
</parent>
<groupId>abc.xyz</groupId>
<artifactId>abc-xyz-application</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>abc-xyz-application</name>
<description>abc-xyz-application services</description>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <sonar.exclusions>**/*Util.java,**/TestController.java,**/IOSScheduler.java
</sonar.exclusions>
</properties>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
        <version>4.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--this would be needed for rabbit mq -->
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.25.0-GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
        <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.163</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--PDF dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.librepdf/openpdf -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.librepdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>openpdf</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.26</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/dom4j/dom4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.icu/icu4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.icu</groupId>
        <artifactId>icu4j</artifactId>
        <version>4.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/itextpdf -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <version>1.50</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.abc.xyz.CrossSellServicesApplication</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: FYI - I have removed the logback.xml file and added the configuration in application.properties. Now it is working

Comment: Any solution on this. I also see the same problem.

Comment: @RobinKuttaiah , check the comment above

Answer (score 1):

This is due to a security feature discussed in [logback#596](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/discussions/596).

You need to remove `pull-parser` from your dependency list:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>pull-parser</groupId>
            <artifactId>pull-parser</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Your application will fall back to using the Xerces fork included in every recent JRE, which supports the `http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities` feature.

**Remark**: When you asked your question the Dom4j version you were using was 17 years old and had already 2 CVEs published, one of them concerned external entities.

Answer (score 0):

The closing tag at the end of the file </configuration> is missing in logback.xml file.

Add the closing tag of configuration tag </configuration> in the last line of logback.xml file and it would resolve the issue.